# Same mistake but different error report. Why?

Tags: python, error-reporting

Why Python reports about different errors for the same reason, the programs with the 1 and 2 lines of code?

I mean:

```
print(1
```

gives

```
Error: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

but

```
a = 1+1
print(1
```

gives

```
Error: invalid syntax
```

same problem - but error message is different - reason?

sys.version_info(major=3, minor=2, micro=0, releaselevel='final',serial=0)

Comment: What kind of prompts are these: `->`? Or are you talking about Python code in a file that you execute? How?

Comment: -> just show start line of code there, sorry.      There is first, programm with 1 line of code, and second programm with 2 lines of code.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the first error. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I think it's Python3 - sys.version_info(major=3, minor=2, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Comment: @user1810077 Using Python 3.2.2 I am getting an `invalid syntax` error for both cases.

Comment: ;( Using Python 3.3.0 I'm getting correct 'unexpected EOF' error for both cases. Just Python parser versions difference?

Comment: 2.7.2+ gives a syntax error for both cases

Comment: They're both `SyntaxError`s, aren't they? Why does it matter that the message changes?

Comment: Who cares?  It's invalid syntax, and it points you at exactly where the error is either way.  The nuances of how syntax errors are reported is not behavior you should be relying on and can change with every release.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I think you are completely answered on my question.

Comment: This site (http://cscircles.ca) where this comes from uses exec(compile(userCodeString, 'user code', 'exec')) to run user code. I wonder if this is relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first case python is 'looking' for its FIRST line/command.
The minimum for a program is at least one statement. So it complains about early termination.

So the first error EOF (end of File) means:
'Hey I was expecting at least one command and suddenly the line ended...' 'Are you sure the program is completed?'

The second error the previous was run so the compiler 'knows' that this is a program.

and the error is different but it means:

'Hey I for now you have a error in this position, can you fix your sintaxe'?

I hope my non academic way do not distracted you :)

Comment: 2Carlos: Does it mean, what I have no chance encounter "EOF" error in any other case except executing 1-line program?

Comment: You may encounter the same error when you do have 'flow control' like reading tcp sockets or files and it is abruptly 'interrupted'.
So it gets strange when you are dealing with internet sockets and you get this error...you feel like:
'what?? there is no file..'
but after you understand what it means by 'file'.
Geeky notes: The Mainframe z/OS still use the TAPE denominations for  disks and volumes...